# Make text stay inside container at collapse. Without overflow

Tags: css, sass

How can I get the text to disappear inside the collapsing parent container? I want to find another solution than overflow to avoid the scrollbar. Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-frost-jd9ln?file=/src/styles.css) of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but this:

```
.info-panel__content-container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

will stop the text from overflowing the container.